# How to handle "gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data" in php 7

Tags: php, gd

I use php 7.0.22 (Ubuntu 17.04)

When some user upload PNG with truncated data and i use:

```
$a = imagecreatefrompng($path);
```

then I get crash with:

```
Fatal error: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data in ###.php on line ###
```

I try to use

```
try{...code...}catch(\Throwable $e){...echo...}.
```

and

```
$a = @imagecreatefrompng($path);
```

But script just dies with same error message.
Use of `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path))` has same result.

My validation of PNG: I use function `getimagesize($filename)` returns `Array ( [0] => 1045 [1] => 734 [2] => 3 [3] => width="1045" height="734" [bits] => 8 [mime] => image/png )`

How can I handle function `imagecreatefrompng()` or `imagecreatefromstring()` with truncated data PNG file?

**UPD:** It's a PHP7 bug on Ubuntu https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73986
Bad way to make works:

```
$output = `php -r "imagecreatefrompng('$fname');" 2>&1`;
if (!empty($output)){
    return false; // handle error
} else {
    $result = imagecreatefrompng($fname);
}
```

Comment: It's a php bug.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174672/imagecreatefrompng-and-imagecreatefromstring-causes-to-unrecoverable-fatal-err